# Alternative to Omnifaces Tree for JSF 1.1

Tags: java, jsf, omnifaces

I need to render a hierarchical data structure on my JSF page. I need to control the HTML output, because some of the nodes need a checkbox and most nodes need some additional icons etc to display help descriptions and the like. I aim for something along these lines:

http://cdpn.io/vtaHz

[Omnifaces Tree](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree) seems to pretty much offer what I need, but it seems to be JSF 2.0 only.

Are there similar components for JSF 1.1? I already use the Tomahawk library, but its tree component seem inflexible, at least for my needs. Any proposed taglibs must not conflict with standard JSF or Tomahawk.

Upgrading JSF is unfortunately not an option (not even to JSF 1.2).

Comment: you can always integrate http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/ a bit of jQuery knowledge needed...

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [Richfaces Tree](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tree.html) is available since 3.0.0. [Richfaces 3.1.6.SR](https://community.jboss.org/thread/16513) is the latest compatible release with JSF 1.1, so why don't you use that?

Comment: I've looked into Richfaces Tree, but it seems less than ideal. I cannot seem to: 1) avoid icons on nodes, 2) expand all elements by default 3) avoid collapsing of elements.